# Azure Databricks Scala : How to replace rows following a respective hirarchy

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Having in mind the following dataset:

[image]

I would like to obtain

[image]

As you can see, basically the idea is to follow the path indicated by column ACTUAL_ID until it is null (if it wasn't already)

I tried to use a udf where I was passing the full initial Dataframe and the recursively would find what I want but it seems it is not possible to pass Dataframes to UDFs. I also looked into replacing a value of a row, but it seems that is not possible.

My latest attempt:

```
def calculateLatestImdate(df: DataFrame, lookupId: String) : String = {
  var foundId = df.filter($"ID" === lookupId).select($"ACTUAL_ID").first.getAs[String]("ID");
  if (foundId == "" || foundId == null)
  {
    lookupId
  }
  else
  {
    calculateLatestImdate(df, foundId);
  }
}

val calculateLatestImdateUdf = udf((df:DataFrame, s:String) => {
  calculateLatestImdate(df,s)
})

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("1", "", "A"), ("2", "3", "B"), ("3", "6", "C"), ("4", "5", "D"), ("5", "", "E"), ("6", "", "F"))).toDF("ID","ACTUAL_ID", "DATA")

val finalDf = df.withColumn("FINAL_ID", when(isEmpty($"ACTUAL_ID"), $"ID").otherwise(calculateLatestImdateUdf(df, $"ACTUAL_ID")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked a bit like a graph problem to me so I worked up an answer using Scala and graphframes.  It makes use of the [connectedComponents](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#connected-components) algorithm and the `outDegrees` method of the graphframe.  I've made an assumption that the end of each tree is unique as per your sample data but this assumption needs to be checked.  I'd be interested to see what the performance is like with more data, but let me know what you think of the solution.

The complete script:

```
// NB graphframes had to be installed separately with the right Scala version 
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.graphframes._


// Create the test data

// Vertices dataframe
val v2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  ( 1, 0, "A" ), ( 2, 3, "B" ), ( 3, 6, "C" ),
    ( 4, 5, "D" ), ( 5, 0, "E" ), ( 6, 0, "F" )
)).toDF("id", "actual_id", "data")

// Edge dataframe
val e2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  (2, 3, "is linked to"),
  (3, 6, "is linked to"),
  (4, 5, "is linked to")
)).toDF("src", "dst", "relationship")


// Create the graph frame
val g2 = GraphFrame(v2, e2)
print(g2)


// The connected components adds a component id to each 'group'
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/graphframes-example-connected-components")

val components = g2.connectedComponents.run() // doesn't work on Spark 1.4
display(components)




// "end" of tree nodes have no outDegree, so add that in to the component df
val endOfTree = components.join(g2.outDegrees, Seq("id"), "left")
  .select("component", "data")
  .where("outDegree is null")

endOfTree.show()


components.as("c").join(endOfTree.as("t"), $"c.component" === $"t.component")
  .select($"c.id", $"c.component", $"t.data")
  .orderBy("id")
  .show()
```

My results:

[image: My results]

If your data is already in a dataframe, it's easy to generate the edges dataframe from your original with just a `select` and a `where` filter, eg

```
// Create the GraphFrame from the dataframe
val v2 = df

val e2 = df
  .select("id", "actual_id")
  .withColumn("rel", lit("is linked to"))
  .where("actual_id > 0")
  .toDF("src", "dst", "rel")

val g2 = GraphFrame(v2, e2)
print(g2)

g2.vertices.show()
g2.edges.show()
```

Comment: What you show seems to work, the only thing i don't like is the fact that i need to have the connections in a separate dataframe (your variable e2), which for a generic case is unknown but i guess it could be calculated with a simple select where actual_id is null.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, but you're right - it's easy to generate the edges dataframe prior to creating the GraphFrame with just a `select` and `where`.  I'd be interested to try out the two approaches with some meaningful volume - what sort of volumes are you looking at?  I might create some dummy data if required.

Comment: This will be used against a csv that has 80MB (around a few hundred thousand rows). I haven't tried you method yet, but will try to check it.

Comment: Hi, how did you get on with this at volume?  I'm interesting to know how it performed and if the graph approach ended up being a good one for this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

Believe I have found an answer to my problem.

```
def calculateLatestId(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  var joinedDf = df.as("df1").join(df.as("df2"), $"df1.ACTUAL_ID" === $"df2.ID", "outer").withColumn("FINAL_ID", when($"df2.ID".isNull, $"df1.ID").when($"df2.ACTUAL_ID".isNotNull, $"df2.ACTUAL_ID").otherwise($"df2.ID")).select($"df1.*", $"FINAL_ID").filter($"df1.ID".isNotNull)

  val differentIds = joinedDf.filter($"df1.ACTUAL_ID" =!= $"FINAL_ID")

  joinedDf = joinedDf.withColumn("ACTUAL_ID", $"FINAL_ID").drop($"FINAL_ID")
  
  if(differentIds.count > 0)
  {
    calculateLatestId(joinedDf)
  }
  else
  {
    joinedDf = joinedDf.as("df1").join(joinedDf.as("df2"), $"df1.ACTUAL_ID" === $"df2.ID", "inner").select($"df1.ID", $"df2.*").drop($"df2.ID")
    joinedDf
  }
}
```

I believe the performance can be improved somehow, probably by reducing the amount of rows after each iteration and at the end do some sort of join + clean up.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.