# Graph processing of two columns in PySparks / Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Let's assume I have following dataframe with two columns

```
value_1| value_2
----------------
      1|       2
      2|       3
      4|       5
      6|       5
      4|       6
```

Now I want to cluster all my values to a new dataframe, where column ***ID*** holds each appearing value and column ***cluster_ID*** represents the minimum value of all values which have somehow appeared together:

```
ID  | cluster_ID
----------------
   1|          1
   2|          1
   3|          1
   4|          4
   5|          4
   6|          4
```

Please note, that even if the values 1 and 3 have now direct link, they still are clustered together in the (1, 2, 3) cluster, because both have one connection with the value 2.

Due to the fact that I had no idea how to solve this in a Sparks way, I've tried to do the following:

First I've created a list of lists with all ID pairs:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 5], [4, 6]]
```

Then I've created a list of lists, where each sublist represented the cluster with this for loop:

```
id_pair_list = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 5], [4, 6]]

duplicate_list = []

for e in id_pair_list:
  if not duplicate_list:
    duplicate_list = [e]
  else:
    try:
      index = next(i for i, value in enumerate(duplicate_list) if e[0] in value)
      updated_list = duplicate_list[index] 
      updated_list.append(e[1])       
      duplicate_list[index] = updated_list
    except StopIteration:
      pass
      try:
        index = next(i for i, value in enumerate(duplicate_list) if e[1] in value)
        updated_list = duplicate_list[index]
        updated_list.append(e[0]) 
        duplicate_list[index] = updated_list
      except StopIteration:
        duplicate_list.append(e)   
        
set_duplicate_list = []
for e in duplicate_list:
  set_duplicate_list.append(sorted(list(set(e))))
```

The result looked like this, as desired:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

After this I've created my new dataframe like this:

```
id_mapping_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[set_duplicate_list]], 
    ['col']
).select(
    F.explode('col').alias('ID')
).withColumn(
    'cluster_id', 
    F.array_min('ID')
).withColumn(
    'ID', 
    F.explode('ID')
)
```

which gave me my final result

... BUT ...

unfortunately this only worked with my small example dataset.
When I've tried this with my larger real data dataset, I suddenly had the problem, that some values have appeared in multiple cluster sublists, which should not be the case.

I guess this has happened, because for loops with Sparks are an anti-pattern, and that through distributing the workload on my 4 nodes, Sparks did not maintain one constant state of my cluster-list.

How can I solve this in a better Sparks compatible way?

THX & BR
Into Numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looked more like a graph problem to me rather than clustering.  In Databricks you can use GraphFrames by uploading the relevant GraphFrames libary to the cluster.  The [connectedComponents](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/user-guide-python.html) algorithm works out the groups.  I used graphframes-0.8.0-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar, this depends on your Spark (3.x) and Scala version (2.12.x)

Here's a simple example:

#### Cell1

```
%python
from graphframes import *

# Vertices dataframe
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame((
  ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 3 ), ( 4, 5 ),
  ( 6, 5 ), ( 4, 6 )
)).toDF("id", "id2")

## Edge dataframe
e = sqlContext.createDataFrame((
  (1, 2, "is linked to"),
  (2, 3, "is linked to"),
  (4, 5, "is linked to"),
  (6, 5, "is linked to"),
  (4, 6, "is linked to") 
)).toDF("src", "dst", "relationship")


## Create the graph frame
g = GraphFrame(v, e)
print(g)
```

#### Cell2

```
%python
## The connected components adds a component id to each 'group'
sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/graphframes-example-connected-components")

components = g.connectedComponents() ## doesn't work on Spark 1.4
display(components)
```

At this point, the `components` dataframe will contain all the information you need:

[image: My results]

You can manipulate it further if required, eg save it to a temp view and run some conventional SQL on it:

#### Cell3

```
%python
components.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
```

#### Cell 4

```
%sql
SELECT id, component
FROM tmp
UNION
SELECT id2, component
FROM tmp
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

SQL results:
[image: SQL Results]

If your data is already in a dataframe it's easy to generate the edges dataframe from your original with just a select and a where filter, eg see here for a [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744696/azure-databricks-scala-how-to-replace-rows-following-a-respective-hirarchy).

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like clustering to me. If you want to do clustering using Spark, you can find several ideas of where to start using the link below.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

Comment: you are right, I've changed the title to graph processing

Comment: Wow. That looks very cool. I learned something new today. Thanks!!